# Xbee Address problem for making a breadcrumb network

Tags: xbee

Sir , i am trying to make a breadcrumb network using raspberryPi and Xbees. Please tell what destination address should i put in Coordinator node so that it receives data only from a single router.I am using all Xbees in API modes. Thanks in advance.[Image of the Addresses of my xbees i am using.[Click to get image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e4yB.jpg)

Router3                           Router2                               Router1                             Coordinator

Please suggest what addresses should i put so that Router3  send data to Router2,   Router2 to Router1  and Router1 to Coordinator.

If suppose Router3 send some data, it first goes to Router2, then to Router1 and then reaches Coordinator.

I am trying to connect the GPS to all the Router RaspberryPis and trying to send these  to Coordinator Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a mesh network, you direct your message to the final destination and the nodes take care of relaying it as necessary to reach the destination.

So nothing to do on the coordinator, and each router uses a destination address of 0 in their API frames to send to the coordinator.

If you really want to force the messages to hop from router to router, just use the router's 64-bit address (the `ATSH` and `ATSL` values) in the API frames you're using to send your data.  When you receive a frame on a node, just replace the destination address with the next hop and resend it.

Comment: Please see the picture. Are the addresses put by me correct? If i keep them sufficiently apart, will the hoping from Router to Router works.?

Comment: Should i replace the device.send_data_broadcast(....)  python command with   some unicast command specifying the MAC Address.

Comment: If you're using API mode, the module ignores the `DH` and `DL` settings.  API frames include the destination address.  Note that by manually hopping your messages from router to router, you will lose the original source of the message unless you include it in the payload.

Comment: If you configure the routers for Transparent Mode, with `DH` and `DL` set to 0, any data that comes in on the serial port will come out on the coordinator's serial port as an API frame (with length, source address, data and checksum).  The coordinator will know which device sent the data, and can direct data to any router's serial port by using its 64-bit address as the destination of the API frame.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for clearing the logic. Please send me some link regarding the xbee programming in python. My project is presently not at all working as breadcrumb.

Comment: Here's a good start for writing Python code to interface with an XBee: https://github.com/digidotcom/python-xbee

Comment: BTW, increase your baud rate to 115200bps or even 230400bps to improve throughput.  Relaying data through multiple nodes is already introducing delays/latency.  You'll want to minimize the amount of time you spend sending data over the serial connection between your Raspberry Pis and the XBee modules.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Your guidance worked. I will also change the baud rates because system is slow. Please clarify, should i put the baud rates like 230400 bps same  in all the Routers and Coordinator, or should i put in some increasing or decreasing order.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set baud rates to whatever you like -- it's the speed your host processor communicates with the attached XBee radio.  After you send your API frame, it sends it over the air at 250kbps.  The module that receives the message sends it out over its serial port at whatever the configured baud rate is.  Higher baud rates mean more bytes/second transferred and reduce overall time required to send data.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your continuous help.